# Dynamically display JSON object in descending order in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to display a JSON object in descending order that is returned to my blade template that should look the output below

```
2007 | 30 | 28 | 5 | 2 | -10
2008 | 55 | 43 | 23 | 0.5 | -1
```

JSON looks like this

```
{
    "2007":{
        "number-xx" : "5",
        "number-aa" : "30",
        "number-ef" : "2",
        "number-sa" : "-10",
        "number-ab" : "28",
    },
    "2008":{
        "number-xx" : "-1",
        "number-aa" : "0.5",
        "number-ef" : "23",
        "number-sa" : "55",
        "number-ab" : "43",    
    }
}
```

So far I have something like this that shows the year and the numbers if I manually declare them so I can't really set it in descending order.

```
@foreach ($data['quilt_data_obj'] as $year => $obj)
    {{ $year }} | {{ $obj['number-xx'] }} | {{ $obj['number-aa'] }} | {{ $obj['number-ef'] }} | {{ $obj['number-sa'] }} | {{ $obj['number-ab'] }}
@endforeach
```

But I'm just not sure how I can get it to show the numbers dynamically in descending order in my blade template.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How about putting this before your @foreach `@php
    foreach($data['quilt_data_obj'] as $year=>$data) { krsort($data); $data['quilt_data_obj'][$year] = $data; } 
@endphp`

Comment: @Yolo tried there is no output with this solution =/

Answer (score 0):

Before the JSON gets sent to the blade template, mutate it in your controller:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data as $key => &$arr) {
   natsort($arr);
   $arr = array_reverse($arr);
}
```

Keys will be maintained in this way. Natsort will handle negative numbers and decimals, and array reverse will make it highest to lowest.